# I have five pages of input data fields should inserted into five different table linking the primary key how to design backend node api

Tags: node.js, express

I have input fields of customer of 5 pages and insert the data into 5 different tables linking with primary key

Can I do it single api or have different api for different pages

tables like custome-master , addresstable , bankdetailstable, contacttable

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write separate services for each operation, and one service to combine them. In the controller, you just expose them. If you are new to programming it's better to write all, a good exercise and also will let you expand/change when needed.